# Google Drive - Get Image sizes

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, images

Is there a script that I can use to get the images sizes within a folder on google drive?

Comment: Is this GAS library useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp

Comment: How do I use this, the Script ID doesn't work, I tried this script function getSize_doc(blob) {
  var docfile = Drive.Files.insert({
    title: "temp",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
  }).getId();
  var img = DocumentApp.openById(docfile).insertImage(0, blob);
  Drive.Files.remove(docfile);
  return {width: img.getWidth(), height: img.getHeight()};
}

This didn't work either - ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: It's probably useful, it's just that I can't seem to get it to work :-)

Comment: No No, you are right. I think that the problem is my explanation and poor English skill. I have to apologize for this situation. Can I ask you about your situation? In your situation, you cannot use the GAS library. Is my understanding correct?